# Are static functions any better than globals?

Tags: php

In instance where I find myself wanting to use a global variable, I often give myself permission to use a static function instead. So instead of

```
global $verbose;
if ( $verbose ) { ... }
```

I do

```
function verbose($status = NULL) {
  static $current_status;
  if ( is_bool($status) ) {
    $current_status = $status;
  }
  return $current_status;
}
```

This basically accomplishes the same thing; is it any better or as bad as using global variables?

Comment: you have my permission to use static or global, or dance naked and howl at the moon(death star)

Comment: I think they are both bad. Code gets tied and harder to test when you're using either one. Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201511/global-vs-function-vs-static-class-method) and this [blog post](https://www.phparch.com/2010/03/static-methods-vs-singletons-choose-neither/).

Comment: conceptually you are doing the same thing only you are adding function call overhead to the mix